# Variational autoencoder cannot train with smal input values

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am using a variational autoencoder to reconstruct images in tensorflow 2.0 with the Keras API. My model's architecture looks like that: [image]

The lambda layer uses a function to sample from a normal distribution which looks like that:

```
def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape =(1,1,16))
    return z_mean + K.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon
```

My hyperparameters are as follows:

```
epochs = 50
batch size =16
num_training = 1800
num_val = 100
num_test = 100
learning rate = 0.001
exponential decay = 0.9 * initial learning rate (calculated every 5 epochs)
optimizer = Adam
shuffle = True
```

I am using the following loss:

```
    def vae_loss(y_pred, y_gt):
        mse_loss = mse(y_pred, y_gt)
        z_mean = model.get_layer('z_mean_layer').output
        z_log_var = model.get_layer('z_log_var_layer').output
        kl_loss = 1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var)
        kl_loss = K.sum(kl_loss, axis=-1)
        kl_loss *= -0.5
        return K.mean(mse_loss + kl_loss)
```

My weights are initialized the default way: kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'.

My datasets images consist of a randomly placed circle, which looks like that:

[image]

The background has the value 0 and the circle's value is sampled from a uniform distribution between -1 and 1, e.g. 0.987 for all circle pixels.

When I train with this configuration, I get the following loss.

[image]

The KL divergence is of magnitude 1e-8, whereas the MSE loss is stays at 0.101.

And I always get the same reconstruction, regardless of the input, which is an image with a constant pixel intensity

[image]

Now, if I multiply all input images with 500 (eg. background stays zero, circle pixel values are uniformly distributed in the range (-500, 500)), the network miraculously starts to learn.

[image]

with a KL loss of magnitude 50 and MSE loss of magnitude 250 (last epochs)

And the image reconstruction works well. Basically, the MSE metric is high, but the circle contour is positioned in the right place.

[image]

**My quiestion is: How come the network cannot reconstruct images in the range (-1,1) , but does so in the range (-500, 500)?**

Machine precision is set to float32.

I have used numerous learning rates, e.g. 0.00001, but this does not solve the problem. I have also trained for many epochs, e.g. 200, still no result.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with weight initialization. How did you handle this? Also your hidden state vector seems pretty large given the simple problem (theoretically you'd expect four numbers to be sufficient, `pos_x, pos_y, radius, fill`).

Comment: @a_guest I updated my question, weights are initialized the default way in keras. Just tried reducing the latent space to 8 and training for 100 epochs, same result.

Comment: `Adam` optimizer is used with default settings too? Increasing image value by factor 500 will increase the injected gradient by the same margin, so can you try with factor 500 increased learning rate (e.g. `lr=0.5` if you have used the default `0.001` so far)?

Comment: `Adam` is used as follows `optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001)` and I am invoking a `LearningRateScheduler` callback which degrades the initial learning rate by 10 % every 5 epochs.

Comment: Okay, so you can you try to use `optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.5)` instead?

Comment: Oh, sorry, forgot to tell you the result, there are NaN elements in the loss for such a high learning rate.

Comment: Can you add gradient clipping in addition to the increased learning rate? Your network is quite deep so the layers at the beginning might only receive small updates if the learning rate is small.

Comment: I am getting a NaN loss at learning rate 0.5 or 0.1 , also tried gradient clipping. Not sure if makes sense to use it for loss = NaN. Anyways, my MSE loss has the same values as before (0.101-0.102) and the KL divergence is NaN.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210007/discussion-between-daka-and-a-guest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments there is probably a problem with the scaling of the loss. Your current implementation of the MSE loss uses the mean of the squared differences (which is fairly small). Instead of using the mean, try using the sum of the squared differences over your image. The Keras VAE (https://keras.io/examples/variational_autoencoder/) does this by scaling the computed MSE loss with the original image size (in pytorch this can be specified directly https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/234bcff4a2d8480f156799e6b9baae06f7ddc96a/vae/main.py#L74).

Comment: Yes, scaling the MSE with the image size (`mse_loss *= input_resolution**2`) fixed my problem! Previously, the reconstruction loss was very small, hence it made up for an extremely small gradient update and my weigths barely changed, but scaling increases the gradient's value, which is why also rescaling the data previously worked. Thank you!